# Discord.py on_message() but only for private messages

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So, I'm working on a discord bot. And am using the on_message() event, which works both on private messages and on servers. I want this to only work in private messages and am unsure of how to go about this.
If anyone can help me, that would be great.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = ''
quotedUsers = []

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='with myself.'))
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.author.send("Recieved: " + message.content)

@client.command()
async def search(ctx, *, question):
    await ctx.author.send("Searching: " + question)
    

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You have just posted your bot token. You need to regenerate it ASAP.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Discord has started automatically picking up on leaked tokens and regenerates it automatically for you - you also receive a DM from them

Comment: oof yeah, that was silly of me. Fixed it now. :O

Answer (score 3):

A message guild also doesn't exist in a group DM, so you have to check if the channel you messaging in is a DM. You can use the `dm_channel` attribute of a user:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == message.author.dm_channel.id: # dm only
        # do stuff here #
    elif not message.guild: # group dm only
        # do stuff here #
    else: # server text channel
        # do stuff here #
```

Answer (score 1):

When a DM is received, it won't have a guild, so you'll be able to use that logic like so:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # you'll need this because you're also using cmd decorators
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if not message.guild:
        await message.author.send(f"Received: {message.content}")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [`Message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild) - it mentions "if applicable", meaning that it'll return `None` if it's not in a guild, and rather a DM
- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6+

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had found though playing around that when  discord sends a message to the bot as a dm in python this will be done using a `discord.channel.DMChannel`and if the message is done in the text channel `discord.channel.TextChannel`.

i have proved this by putting in a type fuct over the object to see what happens in the Message listener.

```py
isinstance(message.channel, DMChannel)
```